# latex pfg/tikz numeric values and arithmetic evaluation of pgfkeys

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pgfkeys

I have a pgf key containing a Number (`\tikzset{test/.initial=64}` (is this really a numerical key and if not is there a way to define one?)) and want now calculate with that key, the content text of some nodes in my drawing will depend on that value.

I already tried `\pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{test}-1\pgfmathresult}` but it didn't work.

Any suggestions to achieve this (as mathematical expressions, I'll need `/` and `-`)?

whole minimal (not) working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{test/.initial=64}

\newcommand{\myMacro}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1)
            node {\pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{test}-1}\pgfmathresult};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\myMacro

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should define `test` as `\tikzset{/test/.initial=64}`. So it is a new branch in the `tikz` `pgfkeys` tree. See section 88 of the `pgfmanual`

Comment: @BambOo Actually for that `\pgfkeys` would be cleaner. It is perfectly fine, perhaps even better, to add stuff under the `/tikz` branch, the only thing is that you have to tell `\pgfkeysvalueof` to look there. Of course, I would add a subdirectory under `/tikz` and put stuff there.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, funny, it is the same in the end, but not the same path

Comment: @BambOo I agree. Which one is better is a matter of taste, but I prefer to put `tikz` stuff in the `/tikz/` path, and `pgfplots` stuff in the `/pgfplots/` path, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\tikzset` prepends `/tikz` to the path so you need `\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/test}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{test/.initial=64}

\newcommand{\myMacro}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1)
            node {\pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/test}-1}\pgfmathresult};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\myMacro

\end{document}
```

If you do not want to prepend `/tikz`, use `\pgfkeys` instead.

Comment: Thanks, should have known that one.

Comment: `\pgfkeysvalueof` is just a fancy name for `\csname pgfk@#1\endcsname`, so you always have to use the full prefix.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, sure. That's why you need to add `tikz/` if you use `\tikzset` to declare the key, as I wrote.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Yes, but even when you use `\pgfkeys` which does not prefix a namespace, you will still need the leading `/`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, I agree, of course. After `\pgfkeys{/test/.initial=64}` you can use `\pgfkeysvalueof{/test}`, which is different from `\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/test}` by a prepended `/tikz`.